# Multiple testing

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons

I am regressing different dependent variables using same set of predictors for all dependent variables such as

```
y1=beta0+beta1.X1+beta2.X2+.....
y2=beta0+beta1.X1+beta2.X2+.....
```

Would that be multiple testing scenario? If so, how can be adjusted for it?

Comment: What exactly are you testing?

Comment: Hello James, I am testing  if categorical predictors X1 or X2 have any significant association with dependent variables (one dependent variable at a time).  Since there are several dependent variables I am running model for one dependent variable at a time. My question is question is if multiple testing should be accounted for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each $y_i$ is considered in isolation, then there is no need for multiple testing. If the question is whether X1 and X2 have association with the response "in general" (not with a specific $y_i$), then you have to either do a multiple test correction for the p-values or maybe recourse to [MANOVA](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/dae/manova1.htm).

Say, your hypothesis is $H_0 : \beta_1 = \beta_2 = 0$ and in reality $H_0$ is true. If it is a single test at 5% level, then you know that the probability of rejecting $H_0$ (Type I error) is 5%. Now suppose there is one million of such  tests where $H_0$ is true. If you define the familywise Type I error as rejecting at least one hypothesis, then the probability of such error is a lot greater than 5%. You need a tool to control that probability which can get complicated if the tests are not independent.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for the answer. Can you give me an intuitive explanation of multiple testing correction?